# Android and iOS inconsistencies for text in labels - appcelerator

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator, font-size, titanium-mobile

I'm trying to lay out elements for a user profile using the appcelerator api.  On iOS it automatically sets the height so all of the text is shown.  The same code in android seems to cut off the bottom of the text, and I have to set a static height for it all to appear.  I feel that this is somewhat backwards.  Has anyone else had a similar problem?

Comment: Please post some code and what version of Titanium you are using. What you are trying to do works for me in iOS and Android in Tintanium SDK 1.7.5.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the height to `"auto"` for the parent element, it should be just fine. In both Android and iOS.

And of course, the height for the label needs to be also `"auto"`. Make sure to use quotes though, it doesn't know the variable `auto`

Comment: the height is automatically set to auto, but it still seems to cut off the bottom of the text in android.

Comment: height: auto is not automatically set in android. Do you have some code? (edit your question with the code)